# Elasticsearch how to check for a status of a bulk indexing request?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, bulk

I am bulk indexing into Elasticsearch docs containing country shapes ([files here](https://github.com/histograph/data/tree/master/cshapes)), based on the [cshapes](http://nils.weidmann.ws/projects/cshapes.html) dataset.

The geoshapes have a lot of points in `"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon"`, and the bulk request takes a long time to complete (and sometimes does not complete, which is a separate and already reported problem).

Since the client times out (I use the official ES node.js), I would like to have a way to check what the status of the bulk request is, without having to use enormous timeout values.

What I would like is to have a status such as active/running, completed or aborted. I guess that just by querying the single doc in the batch would not tell me whether the request has been aborted.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just as an added problem here: you seem to be talking about time to return from the request. But my experience is that even after a request has returned that doesn't mean that a bulk insert has updated the index. However, I do think repeated calls, in a loop, to the `_tasks` endpoint (i.e. the chosen answer) is the way to go. Or indeed Stefano Bocconi's more precise refinement of it (in his comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but may be helpful. Whenever I'm curious about what my cluster is doing, I check out the [tasks API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html).

The tasks API shows you all of the tasks that are currently running on your cluster. It will give you information about individual tasks, such as the task ID, start time, and running time. Here's the command:

`curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_tasks?group_by=parents | python -m json.tool`

Comment: I think this is the closest I could use to read the status of my request, specifically using `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_tasks?actions=indices:data/write/bulk*&detailed'` and trying to parse what requests are still pending.

Comment: Have you found out a way to check if the indexing was successful  or failed? 
I am stuck at a very similar problem in bulk update.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch doesn't provide a way to check the status of an ongoing `Bulk` request- documentation reference [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).

First, check that your request succeeds with a smaller input, so you know there is no problem with the way you are making the request. Second, try dividing the data into smaller chunks and calling the `Bulk` API on them in parallel.

You can also try with a higher `request_timeout` value, but I guess that is something you don't want to do.

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1517410/ketan-vijayvargiya, I tried a couple of requests and they work, so I guess the syntax is correct. I could try with a smaller bulk but I think ES has an issue as reported by me here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23670, so I was looking for a way to detect that.

Answer (score 0):

just a side note hint, of why your requests might take a lot of time (unless you are just indexing too many in a single bulk run). If you have configured your own `precision` for geo shapes, also make sure you are configuring `distance_error_pct`, otherwise no error is assumed, resulting in documents with a lot of terms that take a lot of time indexing.

Comment: distance_error_pct was very useful for my bulk indexing, although it does not solve the problem, it helps make it not likely to appear.